# Is Netlogo implementation of rngs:rnd-negbinomial getting the wrong results?

Tags: netlogo, mean, distribution

I'd like to use the negative binomial distribution to assign values to turtles, but the outcome seems not to be correct.

In my model I'd like to assign values with the negative binomial distribution to the breeds-own variable `time-treatment` of the breed `children`.

I used the following code for this:

```
extensions [ rngs ]

breed [children child]
children-own [
  time-treatment
]

to setup
  clear-all
  rngs:init
  rngs:set-seed 1 500
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  create-children 100 [
     setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     set time-treatment rngs:rnd-negbinomial 1 20 0.78
  ]
  tick
end
```

When showing results and calculating the mean of *time-treatment* the value will be around 70.

[image]

However, according the [mathematical formula](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/negative-binomial-distribution) for the mean, it should be r(1-p)/p = 20(1-0.78)/0.78 = 5.641... How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse formula rp/(1-p) gives 70.91 which is very close to the result you got here. I assume that is where the problem lies.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) there are a few alternative formulations of the negative binomial distribution.
The link you provided counts the number of failures before 20 successes happen, whereas it looks like the formula here counts the number of successes before 20 failures happen.